# How to import variable from another file

Tags: python, file, import

I'm fairly new to Python. Here's the code in 'file1'

```
phrases = []
buildWord = ""

file = open("words.txt")
words = file.read()
for i in words:
    if(i == "\n"):
        phrases.append(buildWord)
        buildWord = ""
    else:
        buildWord += i
file.close()
```

Basically, there's a loop that gets all words in a file called 'words.txt' and appends them into a list called phrases. Now, in 'file2' I would like to simply import this phrases variable to use. Here's the code used in 'file2'

```
from 'file1' import phrases
```

This throws an error "no module named, is not a package". Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You should name your `file1` as `file1.py` and import it like: `from file1 import phrases`

Comment: remove the '' from file1

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '    ' from 'file1' and try this: `from file1 import phrases`

#### Edit:

Someone in the comment said you should rename your file1 to file1.py. Make sure to do that too :)